# Get page number of selected paragraph

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, paragraph, page-numbering

I would like to get a page number of selected paragraph. I want to create something like content.
Now i have this:

```
 while (searchResult = body.findElement(searchType, searchResult)) {
   var par = searchResult.getElement().asParagraph();

   if (par.getHeading() == searchHeading) {

    headers.push(par.getText());

 }
```

And this gives me an array of names (headers), but i would like to create second array with page numbers, where the header was found.

Thanks a lot.